# How do I find and modify just numbers on a webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to identify just the number elements of a webpage and be able to modify just the numbers. For instance, if the text on a page is "And there were 300 deaths in Syria", I want to be able to identify that '300' and be able to change its value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The duplicate is about wrapping numbers in a span, but the same principle applies to modifying the number values - you could call `.replace()` with a function as the second argument to do more complicated things to the number in question.